# For Loop over Data/Rows from a DataSource/Select-Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Here's the use case:
Users enter the budget of each month. So there is a table with the fields [Year], [Month] and [BudgetValue].

Example:

```
2014  01  200'000.-
2014  02  250'000.-
```

For each of those entries, I would like to select the working-day dates from my DimDate. For example, for January 2014 I would get 23 dates. (In my DimDate I have a bit which mark all the working days)

In my actual FactBudget I would then insert a dayly budget with the 23 dates.

Example:

```
2014.01.02   (200'000.-)/23
2014.01.03   (200'000.-)/23
etc.
```

I have no experience with the For/Foreach Loop Containers in SSIS. Is my problem even solvable with one of those containers or do I need a different structure/approach?

Comment: What are you doing in the package exactly? Is it possible to do it in an Execute SQL task with T-SQL for example?

Comment: Yeah why are you even bringing SSIS into this?   This could be done with a simple stored procedure.   No loop needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a temp table with values 1-31.  We will call this #days.

Then use that to create your day-by-day records:

```
Select * from MyTable a
cross join #days b
```

This will create 31 rows for each of your MyTable rows, one per (possible day).  Next we want to get rid of the ones that are weekends or not real days (note, I am using temp tables here so you can see what I am doing, but this can be collapsed into one query).

```
Select cast(b.[day] as varchar) + '-' + cast(a.[month] as varchar) + '-' + cast(a.[year] as varchar) as MyDate, a.*
into #temp2
from MyTable a
cross join #days b
where isdate(cast(d as varchar) + '-' + cast(m as varchar) + '-' + cast(y as varchar)) = 1 --Get rid of non-dates, like February 31

delete 
from #temp2
where datepart(weekday, MyDate) in (1,7) --Get rid of weekends
```

Finally, count the number of weekdays in each month, and join that back onto your table (you could also do this with a partition, but a self join is easier to follow, I think):

```
select a.MyDate, a.BudgetValue*1.0/CountDays as BudgetPerDay from #temp2 a
left join 
    (select [year],[month], count(*) as CountDays from #temp2 group by [year],[month]) b
on a.[year] = b.[year] and a.[month] = b.[month]
```

Comment: I am just curious, would this work even for months having less than 31 days?

Comment: @VKarthik - It should. The middle step drops all the results that aren't valid dates (like February 30-31, April 31, etc.).